# Move specific files and folders from a directory to new repo

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I have project with a ierarchy like this:

```
area/ --
     /folder1
     /folder2
     /folder3
     /pom.xml
cd/ --
     /folder4
     /folder5
     /pom.xml
service/ --
     /folder6
     /folder7
     /pom.xml
env/ --
     /folder6
     /folder7
     /folder8
     /Dockerfile
     /docker-compose.yaml
.deploy.yml
.docker.yml
.gitlab-ci.yml
pom.xml
```

And want to create new repo from it with structure like that:

```
area/ --
     /pom.xml
cd/ --
     /pom.xml
service/ --
     /pom.xml
env/ --
     /folder6
     /folder7
     /folder8
     /Dockerfile
     /docker-compose.yaml
.deploy.yml
.docker.yml
.gitlab-ci.yml
pom.xml
```

I have tried `git filter-repo --paths-from-file paths.txt`
with paths.txt content:

```
.deploy.yml
.docker.yml
.gitlab-ci.yml
pom.xml
env/
cd/pom.xml
area/pom.xml
service/pom.xml
```

but seems like it just moves all files from my project include all folders of cd, area and service. So the result of this operation is the original project.

Is there any other solutions to make it work with git-filter?

Comment: You'll probably have to write some Python code. The filter-repo command runs Python code on each "incoming" commit from the old repository to generate the new "outgoing" commit in the new repository, and your Python code can re-arrange the file tree so that you get the tree you want instead of the tree you have.